# Can I programmatically access an RSA soft token passphrase

Tags: windows, powershell, rsa

In my office, we use RSA "soft token" software to authenticate connections to our UNIX servers.  This requires one to enter a PIN, click a button to generate a passcode, then click another button to copy the new passcode to the Windows paster buffer, which can then be pasted into a "password" prompt.

Is there any way to perform these actions programmatically, perhaps from the command prompt?  I want to be able to run "batch" programs that connect to the server.

[This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072628/is-it-possible-to-access-rsa-secure-id-programmatically-for-use-in-test-automati), but not quite.

My guess is the anwser is "no, you can't do that", but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the answer I provided to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125959/power-shell-how-to-send-middle-mouse-click/12133352#12133352).  It essentially involves using SendKeys to simulate keystrokes to the RSA app.